# Entity Framework Core - Not thread safe - ServiceLifetime.Transient

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

It appears that my database context is not thread safe, transient, even tho i specified:

```
ServiceLifetime.Transient
```

in the startup configuration for the database.

**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer().AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>((serviceProvider, options) => options.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking).UseSqlServer(connectionString).UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

**Api**

```
[HttpPost("GetOrganisations")] //Yes post, dont harass me :)
public async Task<IActionResult> GetOrganisations([FromBody] GetOrganisationsModel model)
{
    Task<IEnumerable<OrganisationModel>> organisations = _organisationService.GetOrganisations(model?.Id, model?.StatusIds);

    Task<int> organisationTotalCount = _organisationService.GetOrganisationCount();

    await Task.WhenAll(organisations, organisationTotalCount);

    return Ok(new OrganisationViewModel
    {
        Organisations = await organisations,
        OrganisationTotalCount = await organisationTotalCount
    });
}
```

**Repo**

```
public class OrganisationRepository : IOrganisationRepository
{
    private readonly DatabaseContext _database;

    public OrganisationRepository(DatabaseContext database)
    {
        _database = database;
    }

    public async Task<List<OrganisationEntity>> GetOrganisations(int? organisationId, List<int> statusIds)
    {
        IQueryable<OrganisationEntity> organisations = Database.Organisation.Include(o => o.Status).OrderByDescending(d => d.Created).AsQueryable();

        if (organisationId != null)
        {
            organisations = organisations.Where(o => o.Id == organisationId);
        }

        if (statusIds != null && statusIds.Count > 0)
        {
            organisations = organisations.Where(o => statusIds.Contains(o.StatusId));
        }

        return await organisations.ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<int> GetOrganisationCount()
    {
        return await Database.Organisation.CountAsync();
    }
}
```

**Exception**

> System.InvalidOperationException: The connection was not closed. The
>   connection's current state is connecting.

The problem here is that I call GetOrganisations() and GetOrganisationCount() asynchronous and for some reason, (I think), the same database contex is used for both calls, (different threads).. I Thought that by adding the option:

```
ServiceLifetime.Transient
```

It would solve my problem, (because default is scoped), but no..

However if I add using statements..

```
public async Task<List<OrganisationEntity>> GetOrganisations(int? organisationId, List<int> statusIds)
{
    var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DatabaseContext>();
    optionsBuilder.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking)
        .UseSqlServer(
            "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MYDATABASE;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;");

    using (var db = new DatabaseContext(optionsBuilder.Options, null))
    {
        IQueryable<OrganisationEntity> organisations =
            db.Organisation.Include(o => o.Status).OrderByDescending(d => d.Created).AsQueryable();

        if (organisationId != null)
        {
            organisations = organisations.Where(o => o.Id == organisationId);
        }

        if (statusIds != null && statusIds.Count > 0)
        {
            organisations = organisations.Where(o => statusIds.Contains(o.StatusId));
        }

        return await organisations.ToListAsync();
    }
}

public async Task<int> GetOrganisationCount()
{
    var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DatabaseContext>();
    optionsBuilder.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking)
        .UseSqlServer(
            "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MYDATABASE;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;");

    using (var db = new DatabaseContext(optionsBuilder.Options, null))
    {
        return await db.Organisation.CountAsync();
    }
}
```

Everything works!

**Why is the dependency injection not working as it should?**

**Am I completely in the wrong here? Am I forced to use using statements for all my tasks if I want transient context?**

**ServiceLifetime.Transient bugged?!**

Edit:

**Stacktrade, (some info masked)**

> "at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosedConnecting.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)\r\n
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location
>   where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.d__31.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable.AsyncEnumerator.d__9.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.d__6`2.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable.AsyncEnumerator.<MoveNext>d__8.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.AsyncQueryMethodProvider.<GetResult>d__16`1.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.TaskResultAsyncEnumerable`1.Enumerator.<MoveNext>d__3.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at
>   XXXXXXX.Data.Repositories.Organisation.OrganisationRepository.<GetOrganisationCount>d__8.MoveNext()
>   in C:\\Users\\XXXXXXX\\Documents\\Visual Studio
>   2017\\Projects\\XXXXXXX\\XXXXXXX.Data\\Repositories\\Organisation\\OrganisationRepository.cs:line
>   65\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception
>   was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at
>   XXXXXXX.Api.Services.Organisation.OrganisationService.d__4.MoveNext()
>   in C:\Users\XXXXXXX\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2017\Projects\XXXXXXX\XXXXXXX.Api\Services\Organisation\OrganisationService.cs:line
>   31\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception
>   was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at
>   XXXXXXX.Api.Controllers.Administration.OrganisationController.d__5.MoveNext()
>   in C:\Users\XXXXXXX\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2017\Projects\XXXXXXX\XXXXXXX.Api\Controllers\Administration\OrganisationController.cs:line
>   51"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ServiceLifetime.Transient bugged?!

It is not bug. As we know DbContext is not thread safe, both methods calls use same `OrganisationService` instance which itself was created using same instance of `DatabaseContext`.

```
Task<IEnumerable<OrganisationModel>> organisations = 
    _organisationService.GetOrganisations(model?.Id, model?.StatusIds);

Task<int> organisationTotalCount = _organisationService.GetOrganisationCount();
```

It is a limitation of Entity Framework' DbContext  in thread switching environment. Therefore, we use the following traditional approach -

```
[HttpPost("GetOrganisations")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetOrganisations([FromBody] GetOrganisationsModel model)
{
    var organisations = 
        await  _organisationService.GetOrganisations(model?.Id, model?.StatusIds);

    var organisationTotalCount = await _organisationService.GetOrganisationCount();

    return Ok(new OrganisationViewModel
    {
        Organisations = organisations,
        OrganisationTotalCount = organisationTotalCount
    });
}
```

Downside of ***newing*** up inside Repository is they become tightly couple, and you cannot Unit Test the repository like [this](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit/blob/master/src/Tests/Asp.Repositories.Tests/Logging/LogServiceTests.cs#L67). If I have to choose between ***Task.WhenAll vs Unit Test*** in that *particular scenario*, I'll choose Unit Test.

If you see yourself using `Task.WhenAll` a lot, you might want look at [Dapper ORM](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) which can be used together with EF.

Comment: Aha.. Okey.. Actually I used await without WhenAll at first, but if i'm not mistaken, without WhenAll, GetOrganisationCount() will only be executed after getOrganisations() is completed, so.. synchronous calls? (just to clarify) Thank you

Comment: If `await` is used, `GetOrganisationCount` is called only after `GetOrganisations` is finished.

Answer (score 1):

Also note that in Microsoft Dependency Injection, transient services will not be disposed until the scope ends.

There is a clean way around this which is to use a WeakReference as the Transient instead of TService. The user of the WeakReference can then take responsibility for Dispose.